# QLineEdit set title case

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

Is it possible to use QValidator to set the text of a QLineEdit while the input is being typed in?  If so, can someone provide a push in the right direction on how to accomplish it?  Thank you.

Comment: Explain yourself better, what do you want the QValidator to do?

Comment: As I am typing in a, say, Last Name in a QLineEdit I want the string  to display as title case - (instead of smith, I want to see Smith).  Do I do this with QValidator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to overwrite the validate method:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class TitleValidator(QtGui.QValidator):
    def validate(self, _input, pos):
        return QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable , _input.title(), pos

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    validator = TitleValidator(w)
    w.setValidator(validator)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I made that a lot harder than it was....was trying to use the fixup method.  Thanks!